# A property of generalized inverse distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

According to Wikipedia, given a CDF $F$, it's [generalized inverse distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Inverse_distribution_function_(quantile_function)) is defined as $F^{-1}(p)=\inf{\{x|F(x)\geqslant p\}}$ for $p$ in $[0, 1]$.

Some properties of $F^{-1}$ are listed in the link above. In particular, the 6th property states that:

> If $\{X_\alpha\}$ is a collection of independent $F$-distributed random variables defined on the same sample space, then there exist random variables $Y_\alpha$ such that $Y_\alpha$ is distributed as $U[0, 1]$ and $F^{-1}_\alpha(Y)=X_\alpha$ with probability $1$ for all $\alpha$.

I'm a bit confused about what it's saying about. Firstly, if we take the sample space to be $\Omega=\{0,1\}$ and $F$ denotes the flip of a fair coin, how can we find a uniformly distributed $Y$ given such a finite $\Omega$? Secondly, what roles do the index $\alpha$ and independence play here?

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page assumes that $F$is continuous and strictly increasing. There is no random variable on $\{0,1\}$ whose distribution is continuous and strictly increasing.

Comment: The definition of inverse distribution function requires that, but the definition of **generalized** inverse distribution function doesn't. That's exactly what the term "generalized" responsible for. Wikipedia explicitly says those properties holds for generalized inversed distribution functions as well.

Comment: @LeonCruz There is some lack of clarity in that page. It is certainly not true that properties 1) to 6) are true for any distribution function. I think the author forgot to mention the assumptions explicitly but he wanted to state those properties for continuous and strictly increasing $F$.

Comment: Just one line above the list of properties, the author explicitly says **"which are also preserved in the definition of the generalized inverse distribution function"**, so I think the author just assumes that $F$ is a general CDF. Actually it's not very hard to prove property 1-5 for a general $F$. As as for property No.6, I think it does need some additional conditions, but not that $F$ being strictly increasing and continuous. Other wise, as Dasherman noted, it trivially holds by taking $Y=F(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kavi's answer: the existence of a random variable $X$ with continuous and increasing CDF $F$ guarantees the existence of a uniform random variable, because $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

The $\alpha$ here is the index for the collection of random variables. Basically, $\{X_\alpha\}=\{X_\alpha: \alpha\in I\}$ for some index set $I$ that we omit from notation. Also, we do not need independence for the argument. Independence means that we can find independent $Y_\alpha$, but we do not need that.

Comment: I know that that property trivially holds by taking $Y=F(X)$, **given that** $F$ is strictly increasing and continuous. But the definition of **generalized** inverse distribution function only requires $F$ to be a CDF